# write a program that asks the user for his name and greets him with his name in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and would like to know how write this basic function where the user types in his name and then the function greets him with his name.

This is what I've come close enough(with probably 100 more versions) with the output

[1] hello x...

So here's the code:

```
print("write your name inside the brackets of give.name()")

give.name<-function(x){

x<-character()


return(paste("hello x"))


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Hi, is there anything wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this function:

```
give.name<-function(name){
  paste("hello", name)
}
```

This works as follows:

```
> give.name("The Poor Jew")
[1] "hello The Poor Jew"
```

Comment: Having not first read OPs user name I thought to myself "what an odd, unnecessary choice this answer made"

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct the `paste`

```
  give.name <- function(x) {
    return(paste("hello", x))
  }

  give.name("John")
  [1] "hello John"
```

Comment: `return` is unnecessary.